# Запись информации из textarea в файл

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

Пишу JSP, реализовал считывание файла через java и отображение на разметке(поправьте, если в мат. части ошибся). сейчас стоит обратная задача: по клику на button записать изменения в файл. в мануалах, которые я нашел, все делается через JS, а можно ли как-то action прикрутить к методу из Java?
Также вопрос по отображению считанной информации из файла на разметке. если файл большой, то появляется scroll и у textarea, и у всей страницы т.е. нужно два раза скроллить, если хочется увидеть весь файл, если убираю скролл у textarea, то и основной тоже не отображается и вся информация в нечитаемом виде представлена, как это пофиксеть?
вот, что я написал:

```html
<jsp:directive.page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8"/> 

<%@ page import="java.io.File" %> 
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %> 

<script> 
    function submitForm(x){ 
        if(x.id=='b1'){ 
            document.getElementById('tt').value='??'; 
        } 
    } 
</script> 

<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div> 
            <textarea style="width:70%" id=tt name="Text1" rows="100"> 
            <% 
                File file = new File("1.txt"); 
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); 
                while (sc.hasNextLine()){ 
                    out.println(sc.nextLine()); 
                } 
            %> 
            </textarea> 
        </div> 
        <th><input type="button" id=b1 value="Submit" name="button" 
        onClick='submitForm(this)'/></th> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: у вас проект с MAVEN - ом?

Comment: @Developer нет, да и что зависит от системы сборки?

Comment: у вас проблема с импортами пожалуйста добавьте эти dependency 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

и вот это
`
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
`
должна пройти

Comment: @Developer у меня просто одна jsp. тут нужно как-то через ajax отправить POST запрос на обновление файла. как это сделать я пока что не понимаю

Comment: ок понятно ео когда выполняем код там отображает инпорты либо инпорты были не правильно либо какой то библиотека отсутствует